# Why is the If else condition is only true for the last textbox?

Tags: winforms, textbox

Why is the `if else` condition only true for the last textbox? I would like my code to become true for every textbox that is equal to textbox6.

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from compare", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox1.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box1";
    }

    if (textBox7.Text == textBox2.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to textBox1";
    }
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox3.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box3";
    }
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox4.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box3";
    }
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox5.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box4";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Not equal to any";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does indicate equality for the first four checks, however, they keep getting overwritten by subsequent true evaluations.  In the case of the last check, textBox5, if textBox7.Text does not equal textBox5.Text, any previous "this is equal to..." statements are overwritten with "Not equal to any".  This is why there never appear to be any matches.

Here's one fix that should work:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox1.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box1";
        return;
    }

    if (textBox7.Text == textBox2.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box2";
        return;
    }
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox3.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box3";
        return;
    }
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox4.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box4";
        return;
    }
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox5.Text)
    {
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box5";
        return;
    }
    label1.Text = "Not equal to any";
}
```

I also fixed numerous typographical errors in the verbiage of your message.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox7.Text == textBox1.Text)
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box1";
    elseif (textBox7.Text == textBox2.Text)
        label1.Text = "this is equal to textBox1";
    elseif (textBox7.Text == textBox3.Text)
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box3";
    elseif (textBox7.Text == textBox4.Text)
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box3";
    elseif (textBox7.Text == textBox5.Text)
        label1.Text = "this is equal to Box4";
    else
        label1.Text = "Not equal to any";
}
```